# CSS Animation not Looping

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a full image background slide animation working fine until the last image. When the animation gets to the last image it does not restart.

I have **infinite** set but it still does not work. 
If I change the opacity it works but images get mixed and the effect is not beautiful.

How can I fix my css to slide every 10s with a minimum opacity between the images and the last one loop to the first at the end of the animation?

**CSS**

```
ol,ul {
list-style:none;
}

.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
content: '';
background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s;
animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-2.jpg);
-webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
-moz-animation-delay: 10s;
-o-animation-delay: 10s;
-ms-animation-delay: 10s;
animation-delay: 10s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-3.jpg);
-webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
-moz-animation-delay: 20s;
-o-animation-delay: 20s;
-ms-animation-delay: 20s;
animation-delay: 20s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-1.jpg);
-webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
-moz-animation-delay: 30s;
-o-animation-delay: 30s;
-ms-animation-delay: 30s;
animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-2.jpg);
-webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
-moz-animation-delay: 40s;
-o-animation-delay: 40s;
-ms-animation-delay: 40s;
animation-delay: 40s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
background-image: url(../images/slide-3.jpg);
-webkit-animation-delay: 50s;
-moz-animation-delay: 50s;
-o-animation-delay: 50s;
-ms-animation-delay: 50s;
animation-delay: 50s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}


.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Animating with loop, you have given long intervals for animation about 60s, 50s and so on. i think thats why you dont see the looping at all... so change animation like 6s or 10s as your description. it works fine

```css
ol,ul {
list-style:none;
}

.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
content: '';
background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite 0s;
animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373') 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=00ff00&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1s;
-o-animation-delay: 1s;
-ms-animation-delay: 1s;
animation-delay: 1s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=0000ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;
-o-animation-delay: 2s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-delay: 2s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=ffff00&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
-moz-animation-delay: 3s;
-o-animation-delay: 3s;
-ms-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 3s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=00ffff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4s;
-o-animation-delay: 4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-delay: 4s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=000000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');
-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 5s;
-o-animation-delay: 5s;
-ms-animation-delay: 5s;
animation-delay: 5s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
25% { opacity: 1;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
50% { opacity: 1 }
75% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}


.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

```html
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
  <li><span></span></li>
</ul>
```